# Tell me about the school you want to go. vs. Tell me about school you want to go

Tags: definite-article

Which  one  is  correct? If  both  are  possible, what's  the  difference?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about a specific school, because you know that the listener is considering just one school, you use the definite article

> Tell me about **the** school you want to go to

Note the **to** at the end... you go **to** school.

it would also be possible with an indefinite article **a**

> Tell me about **a** school you want to go to

this would suggest that the listener is considering several schools, and you (for some reason) would be interested to hear about any one of them.

Without an article, it would refer to schools in general:

> I would like to go to school someday

In the context of your sentence, it doesn't mean anything at all.